# Getting the date that a registry key was created/modified in C++

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I can't seem to find a way of doing this, but it seems strange to me that a registry key wouldn't be given a time stamp at all when created. Does anyone know of a way? Target platform is XP 32 bit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[RegQueryInfoKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that it can retrieve the last modified time:

```
lpftLastWriteTime [out, optional]

    A pointer to a FILETIME structure that receives the last write time.
    This parameter can be NULL.

    The function sets the members of the FILETIME structure to indicate
    the last time that the key or any of its value entries is modified.
```

Comment: Is this filetime wrt to local machine timezone? or UTC